# What would be the best way to extract certain numbers after a specific phrase from a string in a column?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, stringr

In the dataframe I'm working with, I have a column called 'weather' with weather data that looks like this:

```
Sunny Temp: 78� F, Humidity: 63%, Wind: SSW 6 mph
Sunny Temp: 103� F, Humidity: 7%, Wind: 16 SW mph
Temp: 88� F, Humidity: 43%, Wind: S 12 mph
Cloudy Temp: 81� F, Humidity: 90%, Wind: SW 5 mph
```

I'd like to use dplyr's mutate function to make create new columns for the temperature and wind speed that is contained in the 'weather' column. For the temperature column, I'm thinking a function that looks at the first 3 characters after "Temp: " and extracts any numbers should work. For wind, as you can see, sometimes the wind direction comes before the number. So a similar function to the temperature column, but something that looks at maybe the first 6-7 characters and extracts any numbers would work.

I have read up on sub, gsub, substr and str_extract and tried to implement each of these for my specific dilemma. I'm just not able to select the specific string that I've described as above. For example I tried:

```
mutate(temperature = sub('.*Temp: ', '',weather)) %>%
mutate(temperature = substr(temp, 1, 2))
```

but this does not work when the temperature is 1 or 3 digits.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We may use `str_extract` with a regex lookaround i.e. look for one or more digits (`\\d+`) after the substring "Temp: "

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(temperature = str_extract(weather, "(?<=Temp: )\\d+"),
         Wind = str_extract(weather, "(?<=Wind: [A-Z] )\\d+"))
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly for the temperature column, but is not working for the wind column where there is a few letters before the actual wind speed number. For example: 'Wind: S 12 mph' - anything i could do to fix that?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(Temperature = str_extract(x, "(?<=Temp:\\s)\\d+"),
         Wind = str_extract(x, "(?<=Wind:\\s[A-Z]{0,5}\\s?)\\d+"))
                                                  x Temperature Wind
1 Sunny Temp: 78� F, Humidity: 63%, Wind: SSW 6 mph          78    6
2 Sunny Temp: 103� F, Humidity: 7%, Wind: 16 SW mph         103   16
3        Temp: 88� F, Humidity: 43%, Wind: S 12 mph          88   12
4 Cloudy Temp: 81� F, Humidity: 90%, Wind: SW 5 mph          81    5
```

While the first lookbehind `(?<=Temp: )` is relatively straightforward, the second lookbehind `(?<=Wind:\\s[A-Z]{0,5}\\s?)` is more complex. This is because of the upper-case letters plus the whitespace thereafter that can potentially intervene between `Wind:`  and the digits.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("Sunny Temp: 78� F, Humidity: 63%, Wind: SSW 6 mph",
  "Sunny Temp: 103� F, Humidity: 7%, Wind: 16 SW mph",
  "Temp: 88� F, Humidity: 43%, Wind: S 12 mph",
  "Cloudy Temp: 81� F, Humidity: 90%, Wind: SW 5 mph")
)
```

Comment: maybe a longshot, but this code is not working on the following strings:
"Sunny Temp: 50° F, Wind: South west 10 mph"
"Temp: 34° F, Humidity: 59%, Wind: North 6 mph"

And I can't figure out why